# How to pass keywords to a Ruby method from a C extension?

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension, keyword-argument

I'm working on a C extension for Ruby and I want to call a method which has required keyword arguments, like this:

```
class Word 
  def initialize(line:, col:, value:)
  end 
end
```

In C, I'm familiar, with calling Ruby methods via `rb_funcall` and `rb_funcallv`, but I can't figure out how to pass keyword arguments!

Here are a few things I've tried:

Pass a hash as the last positional argument with `rb_funcall`:

```
VALUE kwargs = rb_hash_new();
rb_hash_aset(kwargs, rb_intern("name"), rb_str_new2(name));
// ... 
rb_funcall(Word_Class, rb_intern("new"), 1, kwargs);
// result: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Pass it as the last member of the `argv` array with `rb_funcallv`:

```
// initialize `kwargs` as above
VALUE argv = rb_ary_new();
rb_ary_push(argv, kwargs);
rb_funcallv(Word_Class, rb_intern("new"), 1, &argv);
// result: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Pass `0` as `argc`, even though `argv` is length `1`:

```
// initialize `argv` as above
rb_funcallv(Word_Class, rb_intern("new"), 0, &argv);
// ArgumentError: missing keywords: line, col, value
```

Is it possible? How is it done? Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I *think* you should be able to just pass in a hash (`rb_hash_new` for creating it, `rb_hash_aset` for setting values). Let me know if that works, than I can turn it into an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I updated the question with a few things I've tried ... is there another way I could try passing the hash as keywords?

Comment: You’re on the right lines with your first attempt (passing a hash as the last arg), but the keys need to be symbols, not IDs. Try `ID2SYM(rb_intern("name"))` rather than just `rb_intern("name")`. I don’t know if there’s a way of converting a `char *` in C directly into a ruby symbol in one step, it looks like you need to create an ID then convert to symbol.

Comment: @matt it works! Could you add that suggestion as an "Answer" so that I can accept it and give you magical stack overflow points?

Comment: I think @MichaelKohl gets priority in claiming those points.

Comment: Thanks @matt. I posted an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a hash. Note that to create symbol keys you need a call of the form `ID2SYM(rb_intern(char*))` since `rb_intern` returns an `ID`, which `ID2SYM` turns into an actual Ruby symbol.

```
VALUE kwargs = rb_hash_new();
rb_hash_aset(kwargs, ID2SYM(rb_intern("name")), rb_str_new2(name));
// ... 
rb_funcall(Word_Class, ID2SYM(rb_intern("new")), 1, kwargs);
```